# IntelliJ PHP Application Losing Module after close

Tags: php, intellij-idea

Not sure how to troubleshoot this problem.  I have an IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, used in 64-bit, which I use for a PHP project with several modules.  This project has 3 modules, but every time I close Intellij 11, when I open IntelliJ again, I find that the module has disappeared.

Steps that I have used to add this PHP module:
File->Add Module->Create Module From Existing Sources and I select the directory with the module.
or 
File->Add Module_>Import Module from IML  (I've tried importing the the module-level IML file for the disappearing module), but regardless of which I try, I still fail to retain the 3rd module on the restart of my IntelliJ and I end up having to add the module again.

Edit: A hack to get around this issue is to import the **top level IML** file into your project.  IntelliJ will reorganize the project to show the entire tree structure of your folders.

Comment: Sounds like a support question for Intellij

Comment: I always wonder why questions that are exactly permitted by the FAQ are getting closed as off topic. @MikeBrant and others, did you actually read the FAQ? It [clearly states](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) that **software tools commonly used by programmers** category is for this site.

Comment: @CrazyCoder To me this particular case was one that sounds like a possible bug on the software itself and better geared toward support from the vendor, as opposed to a question, for example, where a user was having problems setting up a project using this software.

Comment: @MikeBrant, it doesn't make this question off topic. JetBrains support team monitors and replies here. By closing this question you don't let support to answer the question and help the user. In case other users will have similar problem, they'll be able to google the solution here and will not have to contact support again and again with the same questions, but for some reason you are against it and voted to close this question as off topic.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I completely agree with CrazyCoder.  A very significant proportion of my answers to questions regarding software tools come from forums like these.  Why close this question?  Moreover, if I had received the response from IntelliJ (whom I contacted), I would have been able to post the solution here too, thereby both adding content and generating traffic to this site for future users who trust StackOverflow.  This isn't a case of someone asking, "What's better? IntelliJ or Eclipse?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPStorm handles this more effectively than IntelliJ Ultimate.  I'd say, that's the only way it's not better than PHPStorm itself.

It's not intuitive, but what you need to do instead is [create a new project](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/php-specific-guidelines.html) in the directory containing your existing sources, and choose "Web Module".

Comment: Thanks so much for this tip. Creating a new project in my existing directory worked great